# The script sometimes doesn't run after wget

Tags: linux, bash, grep, wget

The script sometimes doesn't run after wget. Perhaps it is necessary to wait for the completion of wget?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -Eeuo pipefail

# Installing tor-browser
echo -en "\033[1;33m Installing tor-browser... \033[0m \n"
URL='https://tor.eff.org/download/' # Official mirror https://www.torproject.org/download/, may be blocked
LINK=$(wget -qO- $URL | grep -oP -m 1 'href="\K/dist.+?ALL.tar.xz')
URL='https://tor.eff.org'${LINK}
curl --location $URL | tar xJ --extract --verbose --preserve-permissions
sudo mv tor-browser /opt
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/tor-browser
cd /opt/tor-browser
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

Comment: Why do you use `set -e` when you don't want the script to abort on non-zero exit code?

Comment: This is a small piece of a large script)

Comment: This is not really an explanation to my question ...... Also note that you can unset `-e` for parts of your code, if you want.

Comment: In a large script, the "-e" parameter is necessary so that the installation of applications in the list does not go further if an error occurs. But this piece of script sometimes does not work and does not show anything... And I would like to know why?!

Comment: So then use it only in those parts where you think it is necessary..... Or turn it off for a single offending command, where you would allow a non-zero exit code (i.e. `some_command || true` would allow `some_command` to fail).

Comment: But I would like to understand why they don't work together? And what is the best way to resolve this. And not just turn off the script behavior parameter

Comment: _And I would like to know why_ First you need to find out which is the offending command (`set -x` is your friend here). My guess goes for the `grep`. Perhaps no line matches the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like this option `LINK=$(wget -qO- $URL | grep -oP -m 1 'href="\K/dist.+?ALL.tar.xz' || true)` is working. `set -x` doesn't show anything special.

Comment: `set -x` shows you after which command the script aborted, and this is the culprit.

Comment: With `set -x` and `set -Eeuo pipefail` in the terminal I just get this: `+ URL=https://tor.eff.org/download/
++ wget -qO- https://tor.eff.org/download/
++ grep -oP -m 1 'href="\K/dist.+?ALL.tar.xz'
+ LINK=/dist/torbrowser/12.0.1/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.1_ALL.tar.xz`

Comment: Exactly. And from this you can conclude that `grep` returned a non-zero exit code (most likely, it returned exit code 1). Or more precisely: Since you also have _pipefail_ turned on, the primary culprit could be the `wget`, but at least you know from this output the failing line of your script ... and once you know this, figuring out, whether it is _wget_  or _grep_ which is to blame, is then a trivial matter.

Comment: Large scripts are actually where using `set -e` is a _worse_ idea than tiny ones, because you're more likely to do complicated things that run into its pitfalls. The safe way to do error handling is for it to be explicit. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises for a set of concrete examples of `set -e` making code either unreliable or nonportable.

Answer (score 2):

There are pitfalls associated with `set -e` (aka `set -o errexit`).  See [BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

If you decide to use `set -e` despite the problems then it's a *very* good idea to set up an `ERR` trap to show what has happened, and use `set -E` (aka `set -o errtrace`) so it fires in functions and subshells etc.  A basic `ERR` trap can be set up with

```
trap 'echo "ERROR: ERR trap: line $LINENO" >&2' ERR
```

This will prevent the classic `set -e` problem: the program stops suddenly, at an unknown place, and for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

Under `set -e`, the script stops on any error.

```
set -Eeuo pipefail
#     ^
```

Maybe the site is sometimes unavailable, or the fetched page doesn't match the expression `grep` is searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
wget -qO- $URL
```

according to [`wget` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

> **-q**
>
> **--quiet**
>
> Turn off Wget's output.

this is counterproductive for finding objective cause of malfunction, by default `wget` is verbose and write information to stderr, if you wish to store that into file you might redirect stderr to some file, consider following simple example

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com 2>>wget_out.txt
```

it does download [Example Domain](http://example.com/) and write its' content to standard output (`-`) whilst stderr is appended to file named `wget_out.txt`, therefore if you run that command e.g. 3 times you will have information from 3 runs in `wget_out.txt`